# Kalarm plays ogg sound alarms but not mp3

Tags: audio, kde, mp3

When attempting to create an audio alarm (or a display alarm with an audio component), Kalarm plays the audio if the file type is .ogg but refuses for files of type .mp3.

When running Kalarm from terminal, this information is given:

> structure:
>   gstreamer1(decoder-audio/mpeg)(mpegversion=1)(layer=3)()(64bit)
>   ** Message: PackageKit: Did not install codec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownInterface: No such
>   interface 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Modify2' at object path
>   '/org/freedesktop/PackageKit'

**How can I get Kalarm to play audio alarms?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was missing one of the Gstreamer1 packages.**

```
sudo dnf install gstreamer1*
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing phonon-qt5-gstreamer (probably the same package as gstreamer1 with a different name)